# UNIX: Is the i-number same as the file descriptor?

Tags: unix, linux-kernel, operating-system, posix

Dennis Ritchie and Ken Thompson's paper [UNIX Time-Sharing System](https://dsf.berkeley.edu/cs262/unix.pdf) mentions the following points

1. **About i-number**: A directory entry contains only a name for the associated file and a pointer to the file itself. This pointer is an integer called the i-number (for index number) of the file
2. **About *open* and *create* system-calls**: The returned value (of *open* and *create*) is called a file descriptor. It is a small integer used to identify the file in subsequent calls
3. **Purpose of *open*/*create***: The purpose of an open or create system call is to turn the path name given by the user into an i-number by searching the explicitly or implicitly named directories

Does this mean that the file descriptor is just the i-number of a file? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file descriptor in UNIX is basically just an index into the array of open files for the current process.

An inode number is an index into the inode table for the file system.

So they're basically just integers, indexes into an array, but they are indexes into completely different, unrelated arrays.  So there is no connection between them.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Chris Dodd's answer, not only are inode numbers and file descriptor numbers not directly related, it wouldn't be practical for them to be.

Inode numbers are unique to each file system. Imagine if you opened `fileA` on a file system (say, `/mnt`) with inode number `100`, and in the same process also opened `fileB` on another filesystem (say, `/mnt2`) which also happened to have inode number `100`. What should the file descriptors be in that case?

Comment: And to add the addition: file descriptor point to a table which have many more information (e.g. position of file, buffer, etc.). In fact you can open a file twice, and use it independently (you may have noticed that stdout and stderr is the same file, but different caching method may write error message before "past stdout" messages).